# Way save as png in R with plot title?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a for loop that allows me to generate violin plots for my data set and then save said violin plot as a .png where the name of the png file is the main title of the plot.png.

For example using the iris data set if the violin plot made was looking at Petal.width ~ Petal.length in virginica, setose, and verascolor I would like the saved pngs to be named virginica.png, setose.png, and verascolor.png

Here is the code used for my plot using the iris data set.

```
for(i in 1:3){
  #png(file=paste(,".png"))
  print(iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% 
          ggplot(aes(x=Petal.Width,y=Petal.Length)) +
          geom_violin(aes()) +
          geom_jitter(aes(colour = Petal.Length), width = 0.2) +
          theme_classic2()+
          theme(strip.background = element_rect(colour = "white", fill = "white"), 
                strip.text = element_text(size = 18), 
                legend.position = "none",
                axis.title.x = element_text(colour = "white"))+
          stat_compare_means( label = "p.signif", label.x = 1.5,) +
          facet_wrap_paginate(~Species,ncol =1, nrow=1, scales = "free", page = i))
  
} 


#I tried using this line of code to work around the problem, but for some reason the
#plots for my data set are not always processed in the same order so using a list did not work. 

png(file=paste(file=file[[i]],".png"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not actively controlling the species that shows up, but are rather using the properties of the factor `iris$Species` to generate the pages in the plot. The pages will be ordered by the order of the levels in the factor, so if you iterate over pages with `i`, then

```
png(file=paste(levels(iris$Species)[[i]],".png"))
```

will generate the corresponding filenames and png devices for each page.

In order to finalize printing to .png, don't forget to close the graphics device by calling

```
dev.off()
```

The below code seems to do what you intend:

```
for(i in 1:3){
  png(file=paste(levels(iris$Species)[[i]],".png"))
  
  print(iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% 
          ggplot(aes(x=Petal.Width,y=Petal.Length)) +
          geom_violin(aes()) +
          geom_jitter(aes(colour = Petal.Length), width = 0.2) +
          theme_classic2()+
          theme(strip.background = element_rect(colour = "white", fill = "white"), 
                strip.text = element_text(size = 18), 
                legend.position = "none",
                axis.title.x = element_text(colour = "white"))+
          stat_compare_means( label = "p.signif", label.x = 1.5,) +
          facet_wrap_paginate(~Species,ncol =1, nrow=1, scales = "free", page = i))
  dev.off()
}
```